# What constraint could I put so JPADAO should always insert first entry with id =0 and not with id =1

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

I have created some Tables using JPA with Spring support.
I would like to know if there is any mechanism by which we could control the insertion process  of JPA.

Question more elaborate as follows :-

I have observed whenever I insert some data via JPA dao into database. JPA always start id column (which is primary key of the table) with 1(for every first insertOrUpdate).

I would like to insert the first entry with id=0 not 1.

How could i achieve it? Is there any constraint which would make it easy on persistence classes?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Use TableGenerator. Try below link.

[Set Initial Value using Table Generator](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/SetInitialValueOfTableGenerator.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Bala. I am little confuse about this mechanism. I just tried with Table Generator Annotation. It created some kind of hibernate index in database. I need some constraint on my persistence class which will result with first insert value of id=0 not 1.